# Android - Is it possible to sort lists using Comparator.comparing instead of custom Comparators on APIs < 24?

Tags: java, android, sorting, java-8, comparator

I have a RecyclerView in the app I'm working on that I can populate with various items and search/filter/sort/so on. Currently working on sorting.

I have multiple criteria that I can sort by, which can be selected from a drop-down spinner. The values being sorted on in the data objects include Strings, ints, and enums, all of which are fairly easy to sort. However, while some of the sorting options only need one criteria, some require secondary or tertiary criteria (and in some very rare cases up to 4). That's quite a ton of custom Comparators I would have to write in order to effectively use `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`, so I was hoping there might be some way to avoid that.

Turns out, Java 8 has a great solution: `Comparator.comparing(...)`, which generates Comparators for you and can be easily extended indefinitely via `Comparator.comparing().thenComparing().thenComparing()...`. It also has `List myList.sort()`, which I'm not sure of the efficiency compared to `Collections.sort(myList)`, but it feels cleaner to me. And I looked into it, and thought *just my luck! Android has been supporting many Java 8 features for a while now!*

Unfortunately, Android Studio tells me that, for some reason, `Comparator.comparing()` as well as `List::sort` are only supported on API 24 and above. That won't realistically work for me, since the app I'm working on "needs to" run as low as API 15-16. I find this odd, however, since the other Java 8 features I've tried (lambda expressions like `(o1, o2) -> (o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString())` and method references like `List::sort` above) work fine on all API levels in the range I've checked as long as you specify targeting Java 8. And it is a Java 8 thing after all, not an Android thing.

So with all that in mind, is there a way to make `Comparator.comparing()` and `List::sort` work below API 24? I haven't found anything in my Google searches, they all end up just pointing to Android's Java 8 "documentation" or the JavaDocs for Comparator and List. Either something in one of Android's support libraries (seems unlikely) or a third-party library/hack like [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)?

Comment: Third party backport: [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/). Just add `compile 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.6.1'` to your `build.gradle`. Even better: If you work with Android Studio 3.x (desugar toolchain), you can also try to use [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams) which is a streamsupport fork targeted at Android Studio 3.x developers (it's API is much more in line with the official Java 8/9 API where this is possible). In that case add `compile 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retrostreams:1.6.1'`.

Comment: [java8.util.Lists#sort](https://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.6.1/java8/util/Lists.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), [java8.util.Comparators](https://static.javadoc.io/net.sourceforge.streamsupport/streamsupport/1.6.1/java8/util/Comparators.html) = streamsupport. [java9.util.Lists#sort](https://retrostreams.github.io/android-retrostreams/apidocs/java9/util/Lists.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), [java9.util.Comparators](https://retrostreams.github.io/android-retrostreams/apidocs/java9/util/Comparators.html) = android-retrostreams.

Comment: Note the difference in package names, java**8**.util (streamsupport) versus java**9**.util (android-retrostreamms). Interfaces that are new to Java 8/9 have default / static methods in android-retrostreams, but not in streamsupport (there you have to use so-called *companion classes*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try streamsupport library porting some of java 8 features to java 6/7:
https://github.com/streamsupport

They have the class you need:
https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport/blob/master/src/main/java/java8/util/Comparators.java
(it was renamed from `Comparator` to `Comparators` only to avoid name conflicts).

Comment: +1. I think you should also mention [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams). For devs using Android Studio 3.x this is even better. For example, functional interfaces have their real Java 8 **default** and **static** methods. The same is true for all other interfaces added in the Java 8 Stream API.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! Per the suggestions of @Sartorius I used android-retrostreams. Works great and super easy to integrate with Android Studio 3+.

Answer (score 2):

Only a small subset of Java8 operations are fully backwards compatable on Android at the moment. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features

You can get almost all of the java8 functionality that's also backwards compatible with Kotlin however. Is using Kotlin or RxJava an option? They both support the filter method.

If you have a List and you wanted to filter on username and email you could then do something like

Kotlin:

```
list.filter{it.username.contains(filterString)}.filter{it.email.length > 4}
```

Rx is slightly more work, in that it has to be transformed before being consumed as an actual list, but it would be essentially the same thing with the proper syntax for either Java or Kotlin.

Comment: I've never used Kotlin, so while that doesn't explicitly rule it out it makes it less usable of an option for me. And I considered using RxJava in the first place but as I'm also unfamiliar with that, I was only able to see it making the workflow more complicated, not less. I just went with the accepted solution of compiling with the third-party android-retrostreams library.

Comment: I'd recommend learning Kotlin. It usually only takes a day or two for a developer who already knows Java to pick up. A lot of code that devs are contributing/open sourcing is being written in Kotlin, not to mention it's supposed by Google and Jetbrains, the people who make Android and your IDE. You'll get better longer term support going that route than using a third party library, as well as lower method count assuming you're going to add Kotlin at some point.